# Sails/Waterline autoPk removed

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Since in Sails 1.0 the `autoPk` attribute has been removed, I am unable to find a usable solution to having a custom primary key attribute. Which, given that this was entirely possible prior to 1.0, I find utterly unacceptable.

From the hours I've lost, I was able to deduce the following:

Either I have to remove my custom primary keys and replace them with default `id`, which means I would have to go into my code and replace hundreds of instances of various custom PKs with id, which I really do not want to do...

OR I will have to not put the id attribute in config/models.js and copy it into all my models where I do not have a custom PK, another thing I really do not want to do...

Is there any *normal* solution whereby we can define a default behavior in config/models.js and then simply override this in a few models where we need to?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you are right that Sails v1 no longer includes an `autoPK` option. It has replaced this with similar functionality.

Firstly, to answer your question, you can edit the model by adding the a `primaryKey` option.

In which case, the model for a user might look like this:

```
...
primaryKey : 'userId',

attributes: {
  // Replacement Primary Key
  userId: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    unique: true
    ....
```

If it wasn't for all the code changes, you can use any existing table id by adding a `columnName`, for example:

```
...
attributes: {
  id: {
    type: 'string',
    columnName: 'userId',
    required: true
},
...
```

For more information on this, see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?primarykey).